# Is radeon r4 compatible with Blender 2.8?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, opencl

Hey everybody I was just wondering would AMD radeon r4 be compatible for openCL? Since it is integrated, openGL is out of the question. Specifically do you know what GCN architecture the r4 is? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using google for "AMD radeon r4" you get the information about it: https://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/2496/radeon-r4-graphics. What Blender needs is in the documentation under GPU rendering: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html.

Answer (score -2):

Open->Blender->Preference->System->Cycles Compute Device <- select AMD R4 Graphics, and set OpenSubdiv compute: -> GLSL Transform Feedback <- select, next step - render primitive scene WAIT title render next step select GLSL (recommended## Heading ##) or OpenMP.(recommended) or OpenMP